# Creating Spring @Repository and @Controller for every item I'm working with(from database)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc, dao

While working with a project that involves requesting multiple data types from a database I came to a following question:
Lets say I have 2 java classes that correspond to database entities:
**Routes**

```
  public class Route {
  public Route(int n, int region, Date fdate, boolean changed, int points, 
  int length) {
    super();
    this.n = n;
    this.region = region;
    this.fdate = fdate;
    this.changed = changed;
    this.points = points;
    this.length = length;
    }
   }
```

**Carrier**

```
public class Carrier {
    public Carrier(...) {
    this.id = src.getId();
    this.name = src.getName();
    this.instId = src.getInstId();
    this.depotId = src.getDepotId();
}
```

If so, what's the correct approach of creating Dao interfaces and classes? I'm doing it like this -

```
@Repository
public class CarrierDaoImpl implements CarrierDao{

@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

public List<Carrier> getAllOrgs() { ... } 
}
```

---

```
@Repository
public class RoutesDaoImpl implements RoutesDao {

@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

public ArrayList<AtmRouteItem> getRoutes(AtmRouteFilter filter) { ... }
}
```

I'm creating a @Repository DAO for every java class item\db entity and then 2 separate controllers for requests about carriers and routes. Like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/routes")
public class RoutesController {

@Autowired
RoutesDao routesDao;

@GetMapping(value = {"/getRoutes/", "/getRoutes"})
public ArrayList<Route> getRoutes() { ... } }
```

And same for controller Carriers. Is it correct and if not what's the correct approach?

*Sorry* for styling issues, that's my first question on stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest creating services marked with `@Service` annotation (i.e. `CarrierService` interface and `CarrierServiceImpl` implementation). Than inject them into controllers. Use repositories within services because some database operations will require transactions and a better place for managing transactions are services. Also services can do more specialized job which will require access to multiple repositories so you can inject them. And don’t forget to mark your services with `@Transactional` annotation.

Comment: as i understood my approach is correct. what about your answer - isn't repository just an alias for service that shows that it's a persistence layer, so doesn't that really matters?  let me check myself - according to your suggestion I should use @ Repository if I'm working with transaction in a class, for other work with DB @ Service should be ok, correct?

Comment: What @Marcin Bukowiecki is saying is that you should use a service class for processing data that came from your database. It's just a matter of good code structure and a good way of programming. I could ask you: why do you have a controller and a repository ? You could put them in the same class, no? Yes you could but it will be ugly. Here is a wrap up :
`@Controller` : Recieve the call
`@Service` : Do logic stuff
`@Repository` : Talk with DB.
Perhaps, if you just want to do CRUD stuff with no processing, maybe `@Service` is overkill. I recommand you `@RepositoryRestResource`

Comment: I will make it more clear. Lets imagine that we have 3 entities: Employee, Product and a Client.  We will create a repository and a controller per entity (simple CRUD). Its fine at this point but we will need to implement some more complex business logic like sending notifications to our clients/employees or do some statistics/invoicing with our products. So the best place to put this logic will be a service. Just inject required repositories i.e. to a `ProductService` and then inject this to a `ProductController`. It’s just about separating the logic to a proper domain.

Comment: Thanks! Now I think I got it!

Comment: I've got one more question - by following your advice and using @ Service, not @ Repository annotation(and I feel that it's correct because for now my *Dao classes are only about logic, sql requests are in other classes)  I'm showing that these classes are about logical, so I do not really need to use DAO pattern here... isn't that correct?

Comment: Made some reading about my last question - it's still correct to use DAO pattern because as long as my classes that contain sql requests are just java classes DAO pattern provides flexibility in redesigning work with DB in future(there are other features) but that one is key for me because I'm planning to change JDBC to JPA

Answer (score 0):

It's correct to have a DAO for each entity. 
When working with JPA repositories you have no choice but to provide the entity. For instance:

```
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo,Long>{}
```

Same for the REST controllers, you have to bring together functionalities by object as you do.

You can improve your mapping to be more RESTful. To retrieve all routes, don't specify a path:

```
@GetMapping
public ArrayList<RouteResource> getRoutes() { ... }
```

(I never use @GetMapping yet but it should work like that)

And if you want specific route:

```
@GetMapping("/get/{id}")
public RouteResource getRoute() {...}
```

You should return resources instead of entities to client.

Comment: Now I'm using JDBC, but I'm planning to use JPA in future, thanks :)